# From Eclipse to Android studio: migrating an app-engine connected android project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-eclipse-plugin

Has anyone done this successfully and don't mind sharing their experiences? What are the gotchas? The difficult corners? In addition to being an App Engine Connected Android Project (AECAP), my project uses other dependencies such as Facebook SDK, Picasso and others.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort

Comment: @BrentWashburne You would think. Except there is nothing so for about migrating AECAP from eclipse to Android Studio. Have you done any AECAP? It's a particular beast. I cannot simple go to eclipse and click on export. It's two projects in one and they are particularly intertwined.

Comment: This question requires particular expertise in dealing with App Engine Connected Android Project. Many people will missunderstand it and downvote, which is what is already happening here.

Comment: It's a valid question but possibly needs to be worded with a more specific question. I don't know about AECAP but are you familiar with the Gradle build tool used by Android Studio? That should help with some of the external dependencies.

Comment: I am very new to Android studio. I downloaded the IDE for the first time yesterday. And I am starting from zero. I have watched a number of youtube videos but nothing that makes me comfortable moving forward. So I am asking here for help perhaps from someone who has done this before. I can't believe I am the first one needing to do this.

Comment: The following is not an answer, but it mentions android studio and cloud endpoint: https://cloud.google.com/mobile/endpoints/add_module. It may help the OP or anyone seeking to help.